# Jquery adding a class to div with no class name

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<body id="terms_and_conditions_page" dir="ltr">
 <div class="main-wrapper"></div> <---------*  Edit
 <div> <-------*
     <div class="page_banner describes_page_content body-bg"></div>
     <div class="content-bg"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

and I am trying to add a class (tc-content) to a div with no class name so the markup will look like:

```
<body id="terms_and_conditions_page" dir="ltr">
 <div class="main-wrapper">
 <div class="tc-content"> <-------*
     <div class="page_banner describes_page_content body-bg"></div>
     <div class="content-bg"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I tried `$('#terms_and_conditions_page:nth-child(2)').addClass('tc-content');`
but it adds a class to every child of this empty div.
Is there an easy way to do it ?

Edit: sorry guy, I copied that from firebug so it skipped the closing div. See the edit

Comment: Have you tried `$("div[class='']")`?

Comment: Is `.main-wrapper` is `tc-content`'s parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many :

```
 1. #terms_and_conditions_page>*:nth-child(2)
 2. $('.main-wrapper').next()
 3. $('.page_banner').parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.main-wrapper').next().addClass('tc-content');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `:not`

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r89Sa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one div? Assign an id to it, and then you can get the element by id and add the class to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#terms_and_conditions_page > div > div:first').addClass('tc-content');
```

The div you want to select is the child of a child of the body tag, not a direct child of the body tag. With the exact markup you don't really need the ':first' that I put in the selector since there is only one div in that tier.

...which means there is an un-closed div tag in your markup:

```
<body id="terms_and_conditions_page" dir="ltr">
 <div class="main-wrapper">
 <div> <-------*
     <div class="page_banner describes_page_content body-bg"></div>
     <div class="content-bg"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Should be:

```
<body id="terms_and_conditions_page" dir="ltr">
 <div class="main-wrapper">
  <div> <-------*
     <div class="page_banner describes_page_content body-bg"></div>
     <div class="content-bg"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#terms_and_conditions_page div:not([class])").attr("class","tc-content")
```

Will work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `.main-wrapper` should be the parent div? Try:

```
$(".main-wrapper > div").eq(0).addClass("tc-content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("div.page_banner").parent().addClass("tc-content");
```